# IE6 double margin bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

When we float a fixed width div element to the left, the `margin-left`'s value is doubled. Is there any solution available?

I'd prefer solutions not requiring JavaScript please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, setting

```
display: inline
```

to this DIV will solve the problem.

-- edit:

[details on this bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)