# IE6 + 7 - Double Bottom Margin

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin

I'm well aware of the famous [**double-margin error in IE-6 + 7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824175/ie6-double-margin-bug) that occurs with `float`s.  I'm experiencing something similar, but IE-6 is doubling the ***bottom margin*** of a top-navigation bar (and no bottom margin is actually specified anywhere.)

I'm not sure if this phenomenon is an example of the IE-6 double-margin bug, but the usual fixes (`display:inline`) don't have any affect.

Here is the markup and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style type = "text/css">

        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .outer-container {
            background-color: #fbfbfb; 
            width: auto; 
            border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;
        }

        .header {
            width: 90%;
            min-width: 500px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding-bottom: 0.3em;
        }

        .header-left-column {
            text-align: left; 
            padding-top: 0.5em;
            font-size:12pt; 
            padding-left: 2em; 
            width: 70%;
            float: left;
            display: inline;
        }

        .header-right-column {
            padding-top: 0.5em;
            text-align: right; 
            font-size:12pt; 
            padding-right: 2em;
            float: right;
            display: inline;
        }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class = "outer-container">
    <div class = "header">
        <div class = "header-left-column">
            <b>Option 1</b>
        </div>
        <div class = "header-right-column">
            <b>Option 2</b>
        </div>
        <div style = "height:1px; padding-top:0.1em; clear:both"></div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle link which shows the correct rendering: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8GQ/

Note how there is pretty much equal vertical space above and below the text within the top bar.  On IE-6 however, ***the space below the text is doubled:***

[image: IE-6 Screenshot]

**Question:** Is this an example of the famous "double-margin" bug?  And if so, why does the `display:inline` not fix it?  (And how can it be fixed?)

Comment: I think the easiest way to fix this is to ask all your users with seven year old browsers to upgrade. IE 6, by the way, has been released in 2001.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of my users are in 3rd world countries which tend to have a higher percentage of IE-6+7

Comment: Actually, are you sure? http://theie7countdown.com/

Comment: http://www.ie6countdown.com/ . Chinese people love IE 6, I wonder why.

Comment: Unfortunately there are many countries in sub-saharan Africa, the Mideast (and even China with ~20% IE-6 usage): http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Feeling your pain again.

Comment: yeah, it's quite painful. :-)

Comment: http://motherboard.vice.com/blog/why-does-china-still-use-fax-machines-and-internet-explorer-6--2

It's the Chinese goverment's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<div style = "height:1px; padding-top:0.1em; clear:both"></div>
```

For:

```
<div style = "height:1px; font-size:1px; padding-top:0.1em; clear:both"></div>
```

Otherwise IE6 doesn't take height:1px into account, because it "thinks" the text wouldn't fit into the div. You can make it work by forcing the font-size to 1px.